# SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 Inner Join error

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-db

I have a problem with a line on my SQL/Zend query, but I didn't understand about this.

```
public function getByDemande($idDemande, $typeTiers) {

        $select = $this -> newSelect(true);
        $select -> from(array('d' => 'Demande'));
        $select -> join(array('s' => 'Suivi'), 'd."idDemande" = s."idDemande"');
        $select -> join(array('t' => $typeTiers),'d."idContact" = t."idTiers"');
        $select -> joinLeft(array('tet' => 'TelephoneTiers'), 't."idTiers" = tet."idTiers"');
        $select -> joinLeft(array('mt' => 'MailTiers'), 't."idTiers" = mt."idTiers"');
        $select -> join(array('at' => 'AdresseTiers'), 't."idTiers" = at."idTiers"');
        $select -> where('d."idDemande" = s."idDemande"', $idDemande);
        $select -> where('d.actif is true');
        $select -> order('s.dateHeure DESC');

        $resultat = $select->__toString();
        echo "$resultat\n";

        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }
```

I launch my SQL/Zend query, but this throws an error `(SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERREUR:  identifiant délimité de longueur nulle sur ou près de « "" »↵LINE 3:  INNER JOIN "" AS "t" ON d."idContact" = t."idTiers")`

On the other file, I coded to recover data from this SQL query.

```
$data = $this->_getPostData();
        $idDemande = $data['idDemande'];
        $idTypeTiers = $data['idTypeTiers'];
        $typeTiers = null;

        $gtwDemande = new LogisCom_Model_Gateway_Demande();
        $resultatDemande = $gtwDemande->getByDemande($idDemande, $typeTiers);
        $resultatDemande = $resultatDemande->toArray();

        switch ($idTypeTiers) {

            case TypeTiers::BENEFICIAIRE :
                $typeTiers = "Beneficiaire";
                break;
            case TypeTiers::SALARIE :
                $typeTiers = "Salarie";
                break;
            case TypeTiers::PROSPECT :
                $typeTiers = "Prospect";
                break;
            case TypeTiers::CANDIDAT :
                $typeTiers = "Candidat";
                break;
            case TypeTiers::ENTOURAGE :
                $typeTiers = "Entourage";
                break;
            case TypeTiers::FINANCEUR :
                $typeTiers = "Financeur";
                break;
            case TypeTiers::AUTRE :
                $typeTiers = "StructureExterne";
                break;
        }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: It seems the variable `$typeTiers` is undefined or an empty string. Please try to place a `var_dump($typeTiers)` at the beginning of your function and see what the output is.

Comment: Oh right, thanks a lot for helping. $typeTiers was an empty string.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: The next time, please translate your error to English. Not every is French. Also, note that the [Select](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.execute.tostring) class in Zend implements a `__toString` method that returns the SQL query.

Comment: Yes, i defined $typeTiers, now it's work, thanks very much !

Comment: AnthonyB, sorry about that. I will do it next time.

Comment: @TobiasF. Could you post an answer so Jérémy can accept it? It would avoid other people to coming there to help since the problem is fixed.

Comment: sure thing @AnthonyB

Comment: yeah sure @AnthonyB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the variable `$typeTiers` is either not defined or an empty string. Please try to place a `var_dump($typeTiers)` at the beginning of your method to see what the variable in question contains. If it is empty, just don't call your method with an emtpy string by just checking beforehand.

In your `switch/case` you don't have a `default` fallback. So it is possible that your `$idTypeTiers` has a value not in your `case`s, and `$typeTiers` keeps being null. But your call to `getByDemande` is done even before this switch, so even with the fallback your variable would always be null.

Addendum:

You might want to translate the error messages to English, because not everyone speaks french (this also applies to other languages). This way, it will be easier for people to understand your error message without the use of a translator etc.